# Clickable area on gif after animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, animation

i'm developing a website and i need to make an animated section that represents a process of work, i've made a gif that builds up a pie chart with some cool text animations etc.. now i'm wondering how can i make those texts clickable, allowing me to go to the relative section.

I've seen something similar on this website: https://www.millerheimangroup.com/
the "be ready solutions", it's not a gif but still an image with different clickable sections..
Can you help me? Which could be the best solution?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you need to create a image map (https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp)

They are many tools for creating `<area>` tags on a image (http://imagemap-generator.dariodomi.de/).

Example HTML:

```
<map name="planetmap">
    <area id="first" shape="rect" coords="0,0,82,126" href="sun.htm" alt="Sun">
    <area id="second" shape="circle" coords="90,58,3" href="mercur.htm" alt="Mercury">
    <area id="third" shape="circle" coords="124,58,8" href="venus.htm" alt="Venus">
</map>
```

Example JavaScript:

```
$("area #first").click(function() {
   alert("Click!");
}
$("area #second").click(function() {
  alert("Click!");
}
```

For a better code style you can also use https://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: Awsome, i've missed the imagemaps in my life.. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @AndreaBiagioni your welcome ! Image maps are **NOT** responsive. But you can just add this library to make it repsonsive. [click here for github repository](https://github.com/stowball/jQuery-rwdImageMaps)